# How to send string data to a wifi modem by android application

Tags: android, eclipse

Im trying to write a proggram that can send data to an identified modem. I dont know really how i can make a wifi connection to a modem. When user starts application it should find the right modem and by pushing a button send a string data to that modem because some device is connected to that modem. I just want to know how can i connect to a modem and send data by wifi. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You must specify which protocol you will use to connect to the modem. Could you specify that and explain better what are you trying to do?

Comment: im not really familiar with network protocols. there are just some hex strings that a machine knows. it can communicate with modem with a net cable. i want to send these data by android mobile or tablet in distance.

Comment: Does the modem have an IP address? If so, check if it responds in port 80 (http) or another port.

Comment: yes.it has ip address but matter is i dont know how to communicate with it in eclipse android java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your modem has an IP address, probably it's listening in some specific port and you can connect to it by using Socket.

```
InetAddress modemAddr = InetAddress.getByName(MODEM_IP);
socket = new Socket(modemAddr, MODEM_PORT);
```

To send a string you just need to send it using the socket:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
    new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
            socket.getOutputStream())), true);
out.println(str);
```

If your modem is listening in HTTP port (80) probably it's using HTTP protocol and you can use HTTP Client:

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://" + MODEM_IP);
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(str);
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);
```