# Sending data to ESP8266 Wi-Fi chip from Android device

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, esp8266

I have a ESP8266 chip which is connected to the microcircuit. When chip gets value "200" the light is starting to blink 4 times and than it returns "100" value. I need to make an Android app using Java which will connect to the ESP8266 chip, send data to it and will get value "100". I don't know what library I should use to deal with it. Please, help me, how can I do that? I think it is not the most hard question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your Controller you dont need any Libary. You just can use the serial AT Commands: http://www.electrodragon.com/w/ESP8266

After setting up your ESP like this:

In your App you should deal with TCP-Sockets: https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Googles_Android/_TCP-Sockets

Try something like this in an async task:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), Connect_Timeout);

DataOutputStream DataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
DataOut.writeBytes(message);
DataOut.flush();

socket.close();
```

So your ESP is the Server and the App the Client. This should work without problems.

Comment: Thank you for information. Now I have a problem with how to connect to wifi module from Java code and how use AT Commands via android.net.wifi. Do you have some ideas about this? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to Setup your ESP8266 with your Serial Commands. For this you use the AT Commands. The Rest is Android Source Code. You have to use the TCP protocol. So your Android device is sending a connection request to your ESP. After that you can transfer data to your ESP.

Comment: what kind of setup do you mean? I've found some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954309/how-to-send-string-data-to-a-wifi-modem-by-android-application) in answer to the question but the problem is that i don't know what port i should use to connect. I tried 80,23,8080 and app crashes all the time.

Comment: I saw it, thank you. As I know I need to write both server side code and clien code to make a TCP connection. But how can I do server socket if I can't put Java code into ESP8266?

Comment: No you cant programm your ESP with Java. You have to use the AT-Commands to speak with your ESP. Then you can setup your server in runtime with serial commands.