# Sending data to ESP8266 Wi-Fi chip from Android device using TCP sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, esp8266

I need to send simple integers between my ESP8266 chip, which is configured as access point.

I already read through this question:
[Sending data to ESP8266 Wi-Fi chip from Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273886/sending-data-to-esp8266-wi-fi-chip-from-android-device)

But I don't understand how to use TCP sockets to receive and send data, since the ESP8266 is only controlled using AT-commands.

Could someone please provide an in-depth explanation?

Code snippet from the app:

```
            Socket client;

            String ip = "192.111.1.1";
            int port = 80;
            int connectTimeout = 20;
            String message = "Test123";

            try{
                client = new Socket();
                client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), connectTimeout);

                DataOutputStream DataOut = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                DataOut.writeBytes(message);
                DataOut.flush();

                client.close();

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: You use the sockets the same way as always. You need a server and a client.

Comment: But how am I gonna do that with AT-commands?

Comment: If you make the server you can do what you want. Without AT.

Comment: `Code snippet from the app:`. We cannot see where you placed that code and how you call it. Please do.

Comment: Post the logcat to see which exception makes your app crash. I bet it is `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Yes it is android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.    I call this code in a OnClickListener from a button

Comment: You are number thousand who encounters this exception. Meanwhile you have googled for it and implemented the solution.

Comment: Async Task am I right? I haven't had time to implement it yet. But thanks for your patience and help 

Comment: you don't have to use the default esp firmware, you can write a custom arduino sketch that does fancy network things. AT commands are more for using it as an arduino module.

Comment: The only problem is that I am not sending the AT commands with an Arduino board, but with a custom independent Atmel board and the AT commands sent via the UART don't even work properly yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you use sockets or not, it depends on what devices are communicating. Sockets, namely [Berkeley Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) is an abstraction for powerful computers that support numerous protocols on several OSI Layers (IEEE 802 protocols, IP, ICMP, TCP, UDP etc).

From google it looks like that ESP8266 is a small extension board for Arduino. Arduino doesn't have sockets implemented, at least out of the box. In general, smaller devices tend to use their own implementations of TCP/IP instead of sockets, because the latter are too general and difficult to implement. There are a lot of wifi/ethernet/bluetooth-capable boards for Arduino, and no one is actually going to support 'em all in a single lib.

In your case, a microcontroller communicates with ESP8266 via AT commands. So this is your only option. Work with AT commands on your microcontroller, work with whatever available on a remote machine. If it's a computer, you can use sockets there. If it's merely the same Arduino+ESP8266, use AT commands again.

And probably there's already TCP implemented for ESP8266, it may simplify things greatly. Otherwise, Layer 2 (pure wifi without IP and TCP) communication is also OK if there are only two devices in your network.

Comment: So how would I implement the TCP sockets correctly, because the way I have my app set up now it always crashes when I try to connect the socket.

Comment: If your app crashes then you did not catch exceptions and erors. So start to make your app robust.

Comment: I have try and catches. I will provide the code snippet.

Comment: Dont need hat yet. Only if it does not crash any more. You forgot to catch something. Find out.

Comment: @Nightmar you don't implement sockets on ESP8266. Sockets are huge. Sockets are no universal solution. Write AT commands for ESP8266 to do TCP communications or find a suitable Arduino (ATmega) lib that handles it instead of you. On Andriod, however, feel free to use sockets.

Comment: @Nightmar if you have issues with your android code alone, try to debug it without ESP8266 first. Once you make sure it reliably sends/receives data, proceed with ESP8266 and wifi communications.

Comment: I already have the wifi access point set up. And I have my android phone connected to the ESP8266's network. How am I supposed to test if the app reliably sends and receives data without having it connected to the AP? When I debug the app crashes as soon as I try to connect the socket, because the ESP isn't set up properly I think. But I can't send data without connecting the socket :,(

Comment: `the app crashes as soon as I try to connect the socket,` Again: Your app does not need to crash if you handle all possible errors. Or only the one that makes your app crash. Please post the logcat. Look in the logcat. It will tell you all. Start with making your app robust.

Comment: `How am I supposed to test if the app reliably sends and receives data`. You could develop a server application running on your pc first. Just exercise with client-server. And don't you want to use the inbuild webserver of the ESP?

Comment: @Nightmar well, your task has two components in it: tcp/IP (socket) communications and wireless data transfer. I'd suggest to isolate the tasks first. Test your networking module on PC via loopback or via wired network. When this part is done and tested, substitute loopback/wired network with wireless. Then fix wireless issues if there will be any. I find it simpler and less error prone than trying to find and fix everything at a time.

Comment: `tcp/IP (socket) communications and wireless data transfer. `. No. That is one and the same. It is irrelevant if wifi or cable is used. the socket will handle all unseen.

Comment: @greenapps however, OP uses something that doesn't look like a reliable wireless client. And it's kinda difficult to debug a smartphone and a circuit, especially comparing with a system set up on PC and loopback. But I don't insist anyway. Just don't know where's the problem in terms of OSI Layers.